# Firebird C# criar uma unica conexão com o banco de dados

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados, firebird, conexão

Preciso criar em minha aplicação apenas uma conexão utilizando o `fbconnection` que será compartilhada por toda aplicação.

Realizei este procedimento da seguinte maneira.

Criei uma classe estática que me fornece a conexão com o BD:

```
static class Conexao
{


    private static String strConn = Properties.Settings.Default.caminhoFbConnection;
    private static FbConnection conn = null;


    public static void Conection()
    {

    }

    public static FbConnection getConnection()
    {
        try
        {

            if (conn == null)
            {
                conn = new FbConnection(strConn);
                conn.Open();
                return conn;
            }
            else
            {
                if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    return conn;
                }
                else
                {
                    FbConnection.ClearAllPools();
                    conn = new FbConnection(strConn);
                    conn.Open();
                    return conn;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro - " + excep.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

e toda vez que necessito de uma conexão simplesmente chamo a função `Conexao.getConnection();`

Minha pergunta é a seguinte: tem algum problema utilizar e ou criar a conexão de forma estática e utilizá-la durante toda execução do programa? Ou ela pode sobrecarregar e deixar de funcionar no meio da execução?

Comment: você está querendo implementar o padrão Singleton para uma conexão de banco de dados?

Comment: Pode se dizer que sim, tenho o servidor firebird em um computador e vários clientes que usam esta conexão para conectar a ele, gostaria que cada cliente usa-se apenas uma conexão para não sobrecarregar o servidor.

Comment: Porque não adiciona a pergunta querendo dizer isso? Na minha opinião a pergunta se tornaria mais interessante. Tenta como colocar Utilizar Padrão Singleton em conexões de banco de dados? Certeza que choveria de respostas.